# Reconstructing a restricted distribution from its mean and standard deviation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

For simplicity lets assume we have a continuous distribution from 0 to 100.

If the mean is 60 and std is 10, then it would make sense to simply model it as a gaussian with those parameters.

However if the mean is 85 and std is 40, then it is quite clear that the distribution cannot look like a gaussian. My question is, what can we say about such a distribution. How could such a distribution be estimated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Several Beta Densities]

I've attached a picture of various beta densities from the wiki on the [Beta Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).  It really matters what your density looks like beyond the first two moments you specified, but in general, this will ensure the values are restricted to a bounded interval.

[image: Several Gamma Densities]

If you aren't concerned with some density living outside your interval you might consider using a [Gamma Density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

If you really have no idea what the density looks like and want to restrict to a bounded interval you determine the maximal entropy density.  This will be the one subject to the constraints of a bounded interval with fixed mean and variance.  See this wiki page on the [Maximum Entropy Probability Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution).  In particular, the section headed "A theorem due to Boltzmann".